# Add a date to output filename using SQLCMD from within SQL Agent CmdExec?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, sql-agent

I want to run a weekly extract from a SQL Server database using SQLCMD under SQL Agent.  Because I need to save multiple extracts in the same share, I want to use the current date as part of the extract's file name.  When doing this from the command line, I use:

```
sqlcmd -S POC -i "\\org-data\data\dept\share\registry\SQLCMD\extractdata.sql" -s "|" -W -h-1 -o "\\org-data\data\dept\share\registry\Extracts\extractdata.%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.txt"
```

and it works perfectly.

When I place the same statement into a CmdExec under SQL Agent, my date becomes a syntax error -- ("The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect")

How do others handle this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the SQL Server Agent tokens. They are described in MSDN article, ["Use Tokens in Job Steps"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx). The **DATE** token provides the current date in YYYYMMDD format. For your example use:

```
"...\Extracts\extractdata.$(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(DATE)).txt"
```

Comment: I wanted to mention that this post was helpful for me today - I needed to make the output file name of a job step have a date stamp and the SQL Server Agent tokens example was a fast solution with zero coding. So, I just put the token in the "Output File Name" box on the advanced tab like this: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test_$(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(DATE)).txt

Comment: This worked well for me. Not sure why this isn't accepted as answer

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working for me

```
echo off
sqlcmd -m 1 -S 10.108.96.210\QA832 -U Exception -P Password1 -i E:\KCM_UAT\Exception.sql -o C:\Test_$(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(DATE)).txt  -W -h-1 -s "    "
set /p delExit=Press the ENTER key to exit...:
```

The file is written out like this

```
Test_$(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(DATE)).txt
```